# How do I conditionally resample data into hourly values only when enough data is present?

Tags: python, datetime, resampling

My first time trying something more tricky and coming on here for advice. I am trying to resample my data that is at times in 10 minute increments in such a way that I obtain  hourly values only if half or more of the data is an actual value instead of a NaN value. How do I still return a NaN value if more than 50% is NaN? So that I still have a continuous time series (at least when it comes to timestamps).

I am working in Python 3 via a jupyterlab notebook (not sure if that makes a difference).

Here's a small example of what I am trying to do:

Let's say that for an hour the rain gauge I am using needs to be repaired and therefore doesnt record any data:

```
Datetime          Precip
2014-07-01 00:00  0.2
2014-07-01 00:10  0.3
2014-07-01 00:20  0.1
2014-07-01 00:30  0.0
2014-07-01 00:40  NaN
2014-07-01 00:50  NaN
2014-07-01 01:00  NaN
2014-07-01 01:10  NaN
2014-07-01 01:20  NaN
2014-07-01 01:30  NaN
2014-07-01 01:40  0.0
2014-07-01 01:50  0.0
```

I would want the resample to return the following output where the first hour is resampled (since it has more than 50% data) and for the second hour to be returned as a NaN.

```
Datetime          Precip
2014-07-01 00:00  0.15
2014-07-01 00:10  NaN
```

So far I have just resampled as such:

```
df['Precip'].resample(rule = 'h').mean()
```

However that obviously resamples everything.

Comment: In which language are you coding? Could you share a [mre], please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Additionally, please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: @Adriaan Thanks for the clear up, I wasn't quite sure when it comes to answering my own question, whether to include it in the main part or as a question down below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my issue with the following function:

In the function, the perc_of_NaN is the threshhold of NaN values above which you want to exclude any averaging. eg. You don't want resampling to be done if more than 60% of datapoints are NaN, then perc_of_NaN would be 60.

Additionally, Averaging_number is the amount of rows (could be timesteps/whatever your data is) that you want to resample together.

```
def NaN_Resample(df,perc_of_NaN,Averaging_number):
    rows = int(len(df)/Averaging_number)
    columns = int(len(df.columns))
    Output = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((rows,columns)))
    Headers = list(df.columns)
    Output = Output.set_axis(Headers, axis=1)
    dec_of_NaN = perc_of_NaN/100
    for x in range (columns):
        for y in range (rows):
            if df.iloc[(y*Averaging_number):((y*Averaging_number)+(Averaging_number)),x].isna().sum()>(Averaging_number*dec_of_NaN): 
                Output.iloc[y,x] == 'NaN'
            Output.iloc[y,x] = df.iloc[(y*Averaging_number):((y*Averaging_number)+(Averaging_number)),x].mean()
    Output.index = pd.to_datetime(Output[Headers[0]])      
    Output = Output.resample(rule = 'd').mean()
    return Output
```

Feel free to use the function/ask any questions about it if it is helpful to you :)